# rand() returns no value in my custom function

Tags: c, function, random, frequency-distribution

Despite having set srand() **only once** as pointed by similar Q/A about rand()

I think the following rand does not return a value for my customized random function.

Anyway my purpose was to generate a few random numbers 
and right after their appearance to count +1 at an array (to calculate their frequency later on)

*One  represents (5x)+1 at freq[] array*

I have read documentation about rand()/srand but I cant figure out the error.

Thanks for your patience!

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <time.h>
#define N 1000



int RandomInteger(int low , int high);
main()
{
    int freq[9]={0},i,j,number,div;

    srand((int)time(NULL));
    for(i=0;i<N;i++)
        number=RandomInteger(1,9);
    switch(number){ 
    case 1:
        freq[0]+=1;
        break;
   case 2:
        freq[1]+=1;
        break;
   case 3:
        freq[2]+=1;
        break;
   case 4:
        freq[3]+=1;
        break;
   case 5:
        freq[4]+=1;
        break;
   case 6:
       freq[5]+=1;
       break;
   case 7:
       freq[6]+=1;
       break;
   case 8:
      freq[7]+=1;
      break;
   case 9:
      freq[8]+=1;
      break;
   default:
    ; 
   }
for(i=0;i<9;i++){
   div=freq[i]/5;
   printf("%d|",div);
   for(j=0;j<div;j++) 
       printf("*"); 
   printf("\n"); 
   }

}

int RandomInteger(int low , int high)
{
    int k;
    double d;
    d=(double)rand()/((double)RAND_MAX+1);
    k=(int)(d*(high-low+1));

    return low+k;
}
```

Comment: Turn up the warnings on your compiler. The code you posted won't even compile.

Comment: Why do you think it returns no number? I can assure you it does. I think the issue is that your for loop doesnt contain the switch statement.

Comment: Turbo c compiles it with no warning

Comment: Doesn't compile nor run http://ideone.com/PCEPPy

Comment: Both Turbo C and Dev-C++ (AFTER 4.5 VERSION not the old non working) compile and run this

Comment: your pasted code is missing a semicolon at int k. Also why not just freq[number]++;

Comment: @nrathaus the site also says that k is undefined , it is defined just locally for the custom function right?

Comment: hell freq[RandomInteger(x,y)]++;

Comment: you have high set to 1 and low set to 9 giving you a -K

Comment: @imsoconfused actually `freq[ RandomInteger(x,y) - 1 ]++;`

Comment: @clcto yep absolutely right

Comment: I am not sure about that @clcto every cell holds the appearances of each number (1,9)

Comment: Every time 1 appears freq[0]=freq[0]+1 right? initial value 0

Comment: yeah, ++ just increments the value that was there before, and you're just incrementing index #-1

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You problem is this:

```
for(i=0;i<N;i++)
 number=RandomInteger(1,9);
```

It should have

```
for(i=0;i<N;i++) {
 number=RandomInteger(1,9);
..
..
}
```

Otherwise it runs it N times (same line), but never goes to the `switch` until it finishes the loop

Comment: could you explain me these lines `d=(double)rand()/((double)RAND_MAX+1);
    k=(int)(d*(high-low+1));` they were pre-given by our professor

Comment: It *does* go to the `switch` after the loop finishes.

Comment: rand() Returns a pseudo-random integral number in the range between 0 and RAND_MAX, so d using the code you have, generate a number between 0 and 1 (instead of RAND_MAX), k generates a number between high and low and using d, makes sure its evenly distributed

Comment: @KeithThompson yeah, you know what I meant, anyway made it better explained

Comment: No, I really didn't know what you meant. Thanks for fixing it.

Comment: Rand is a random number between 0 and RAND_MAX right? Ok the division will always be like 0.xxxx (_unless it takes RAND_MAX_) and it will always  return 0 right?

Comment: return 0, i mean after the cast back to int

Comment: `k=(int)(d*(high-low+1));` the cast happens in the "end" so first d (which isn't round) is multiplied by the number 9-1+1 => 9, so you get a range of numbers between 0 and 9, including example, 4.327812371723754, which when then is cast, gets the value of `4`

Comment: Ok i get that it multiplies the random 0.xxxx with 9 to produce an int between the range with some "noise".(ignored after cast) but can rand() actually take RAND_MAX so output of d is 1?

Comment: `rand()` receives no parameters, so you can do this (rand() * (high - low + 1)) / (RAND_MAX + 1) to make it return, basically the same thing as before, but it will be less "theoretically correct" as theory says, generate noise and multiple by range

Answer (score 2):

In your code high is set to 1 and low is set to 9 this will result in a negative k.  The return will be outside of the range of your cases and will fall to default.

Comment: (1,9) (int low,int high)

Comment: His code lacks the `{` after the `for`, so the code doesn't run, that is his problem, the negative thing I believe is just a silly bug

Comment: @nrathaus yeah there are plenty of silly bugs, good catch on yours too

Comment: i edited the code about 10 mins ago for an embarassing semicolon :D at `int k;`